# vagrant set ip address in loop with maths

Tags: ruby, vagrant

I am trying to write a script to set up a dynamic number of nodes in vagrant.

so it runs as

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  $num_instances = 3

  (1..$num_instances).each do |i|

    $ip = "10.1.10.#{i}+80"
    config.vm.define "node#{i}" do |node|
      node.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu1604"

      node.vm.provider :libvirt do |domain|
        domain.memory = 1024
        domain.cpus = 1
        domain.nic_model_type = "virtio"
        domain.kvm_hidden = true
      end

      node.vm.hostname = "t2-node#{i}"
      node.vm.network "public_network",
                    :ip => $ip,
                    :type => "bridge" ,
                    :dev => "br1",
                    :mode => "bridge",
                    :use_dhcp_assigned_default_route => true

    end
  end
end
```

but I get an error:

```
Unknown interface eth1
Error: ??? prefix is expected rather than "10.1.10.3+80/255.255.255.0".
```

so I guess the addition for the `$1p` variable isn't being done properly?

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This is more a ruby question than a vagrant question but you do your string interpolation wrong so the statement

```
$ip = "10.1.10.#{i}+80"
```

returns a string that is `10.1.10.3+80` and of course this is not a valid IP.

what you're looking at is

```
ip = "10.1.10.#{i+80}"
```

which will make the right math.

You can easily check in irb on your command line

```
irb(main):001:0> num_instances = 3
=> 3
irb(main):002:0> (1..num_instances).each do |i|
irb(main):003:1* ip = "10.1.10.#{i+80}"
irb(main):004:1> p ip
irb(main):005:1> end
"10.1.10.81"
"10.1.10.82"
"10.1.10.83"
=> 1..3
```

PS: Note, you dont need all the `$` when you declare variables in ruby.